# Is it possible to pass a parameter to a MoveIteratorFactory

Tags: optaplanner

I have created a number of `MoveIteratorFactory`s and would like to pass a parameter (`maxValue`) to them. The anticipated effect would be that each iterator created with these factories is then passed this parameter - and consequently change it's behaviour.

Looking that the code and documentation, I don't think this feature exists. But maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version 7.18 doesn't support it yet, but it does support custom properties on several other config classes.
In the exact same way, a future version of OptaPlanner should support it on MoveListFactoryConfig and MoveIteratorFactoryConfig. I've [created an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1453) with code references for inspiration.
(Pull requests welcome :) Otherwise I 'll code it sooner or later.

Comment: Hey Geoffrey, thanks! Very clear. Pull request... tempting! I'll need to focus on getting my demo up and running first -- then I'll give it a try.